# Can I use If/Else statements in a return?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

```
function() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("MagicZoomPlus")[0];
  var image = "https://www.mywebsite.com" + element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute("src");
  return image;
}
```

That is my current code, which is working fine except some images are stored locally while others are on a CDN with a different path. Can, and if so how, would I write it to say something like

```
If img src starts with “/uploads” than 
var image = "https://www.mywebsite.com" + element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute("src");
Else than
var image = element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute("src");
```

Comment: Have you tried what you are proposing ?

Comment: just convert the pseudo-code to JS code. That's it

Comment: `function() {`

`var element = document.getElementsByClassName("MagicZoomPlus")[0];`

`var image = (element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute("src").startsWith('/uploads') ? "https://www.mywebsite.com" : "") `
`+ element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute("src");`
    return image;
   }`

Comment: Looks like you have the general idea correct. <del>You need to declare `var image` before the if so that it's available later.  vars declared inside the if and else will not be available outside</del> corrected below

Comment: All you need is to read a beginner's tutorial.

Comment: @LouFranco `var` is not block scoped.

Comment: @JJJ seriously! Javascript is so weird.

Comment: sounds like you just want a ternary operator

Comment: @LouFranco also if they just want to return the value there is no point in even declaring the `image` variable.

Comment: @KevinDanielSetiono put answers like that as an answer, and explain the ternary operator as well as the thought process behind how to write code using it: code blobs for answers are not effective ones

Comment: @PatrickBarr done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a lot that can be shortened by using a variable and selecting with [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

This also uses an `if` statement to direct the code flow, and the [`.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method to check that the `.src` starts with the value.

```
function myFunc() {
  var img = document.querySelector(".MagicZoomPlus img");
  if (img.src.startsWith("/uploads")) {
    return "https://www.mywebsite.com" + img.src
  }
  return img.src
}
```

So since you wanted the first `img` of the first `MagicZoomPlus` element, we can simply build a selector like the ones you use in CSS, to directly fetch the image with [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). Its counterpart [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns all matched elements..

Then if the image's `src` starts with `"/uploads"`, we immediately return the concatenation of `"https://www.mywebsite.com"` to the `img.src`.

We don't need an `else` branch since we returned in the `if`, so all that's left is to return the `img.src` if the `if` condition failed.

I also fixed the invalid syntax of your function, since it didn't have a name.

Answer (score 1):

```
function() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("MagicZoomPlus")[0];
  var src = element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute("src");
  var prefix = src.startWith('/uploads') ? "https://www.mywebsite.com" : "";
  var image = prefix + src;
  return image;
}
```

You can use the ? operator.
The ? operator works as if. If the expression is true the left side of : operator will be used otherwise the right side.

Answer (score 0):

So just use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). I broke it into variables to be more readable

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("MagicZoomPlus")[0],
    path = element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute("src"),
    prefix = path.indexOf("/uploads")===0 ? "http://www.example.com" : "";
return prefix + path;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary syntax:

```
var image = '';
var valueIfTrue = "https://www.mywebsite.com" + element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute("src")
var valueIfFalse = element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute("src")
image = image src starts with "/uploads" ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse
```

I left your pseudo-code as condition, your job to get it right! :)

For more on the topic, check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator